# Being a beginner why do I have long after pains in my calves and below after Jogging?

Tags: running, long-distance-running, pain, calf

I am 27 years old and have recently joined MMA. They always start with the warm up jogging. We do the warmup jog in inside the MMA joint with those soft mats without any footwear.

Since I am the latest to join, it is me who struggles to keep up in the 15-20 minutes continuous jog. So the coach told me to start morning jogs daily starting with brisk walking.

So for a week, I was doing brisk walking, I had no issues, I was doing upto 5 miles.

Then I started with Jogging, and it wasn't continuous, I would jog slowly for 30-40 seconds and then brisk walk and then after some time jog again. As far as I can remember, my pain started in my calves and below it.

I took a break for 3-4 days from jog but the pain was still there, but it was dipping down gradually. I really felt its affect when I was playing soccer, My legs felt really weak and fragile in the second half of the game while running. I play soccer one day a week.

I am sure it is to do with Jogging because the pain gradually went away when I stopped jogging and just did brisk walking for two weeks, I had no issues in soccer or MMA. And now I tried starting yesterday with jogging again, the pain has come back. The only difference this time in jogging was was able to run 1 mile continuously without any break. But the pain remains the same.

I jog on roads which is only the place available for me.

**My question is if this is a starting pain which occurs everywhere** - in MMA, football when starting after a long time there is muscle pain.

If it is that pain then there is no problem for me, I can continue like with body building, initially there will be muscle pain but it will go with time, if this is the same that every novice goes through with jogging then I am good.

Comment: What kind of shoes are you wearing? Running on a mat you will likely be up on your toes, engaging your calves. It will take time to build your calf muscles.

Comment: This isn't really anything we can answer. It could be old/wrong shoes, it could be gait problems, it could be physical defect, etc. Your best bet is to consult with some professionals that can assess your shoes/gait and any possible physical problems.

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not on point, My main concern was to check if someone who has never jogged is going to start, will he/she have pain for the starting few days.

Like when someone starts with bodybuilding, initially there will be pain but it will subside with time, doesn't mean one should stop, so similarly is it same with jogging?